# use timer to countdown from what is placed in the uitextfield

Tags: swift, timer, uitextfield, selector

My swift code below should take whatever number is placed in the textfield and then count it down in by a single second. I dont know how to take what is in the textfield and get it to be counted down from. Dont worry about making sure the user places a number and not a string in the textfield.

```
    import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

var enterTime = UITextField()
var lblTime = UILabel()
var startBTN = UIButton()
var timer = Timer()
var counter = 33

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    [enterTime,lblTime,startBTN].forEach{
        $0.backgroundColor = .systemRed
        view.addSubview($0)
        $0.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    }

     enterTime.frame = CGRect(x: view.center.x-115, y: view.center.y-200, width: 60, height: 50)
     lblTime.frame = CGRect(x: view.center.x-115, y: view.center.y, width: 60, height: 50)
     startBTN.frame = CGRect(x: view.center.x-115, y: view.center.y+200, width: 60, height: 50)

    startBTN.addTarget(self, action: #selector(startHit), for: .touchDown)


}
@objc func startHit() {

   timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1, target: self, selector: #selector(timerAction), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)



}

    @objc func timerAction() {



        //This is where the user would take the time from uitextfield and causes it to count down
        enterTime.text = counter

        lblTime.text = "\(counter)"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1 ) Invalidate your timer and initiate counter with a value from enterTime textField and start your timer in startHit function.

2 ) In the timerAction function, reduce the counter value by 1 and set it in the lblTime.

You may need to modify your startHit and timerAction functions as follows.

```
@objc func startHit() {
   timer.invalidate()
   if let counterText = enterTime.text, let counterValue = Int(counterText) {
      counter = counterValue
      lblTime.text = String(counter)
      timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1, target: self, selector: #selector(timerAction), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
   }      
}

@objc func timerAction() {
   counter -= 1
   lblTime.text = String(counter)
   if ( counter == 0 ) {
      timer.invalidate()
   }
}
```